# Trying to load page into div, but div showing too small

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, divider

I'm trying to build a page where the admin can do multiple tasks from within.
For example after the admin logs in, he will click on a button to either manage the users or view the reports, but the result the result is extremely small view of the page while I'd like the loaded page to fill the entire bottom of the screen:

[image]

here is my code:

[image]

I looked for explanation on the web but couldn't find any.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the HTML & CSS of the generated code? Can you put it on a JSfiddle?

Comment: This is everything. There is no CSS file in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the element you're looking at is probably the default size for an object in that browser.

You're putting your file/data directly into an object with type text/html; to be honest, I'd suggest looking into a bit more background information on how to display data on the web using tables and/or grids without actually dumping pure file-info into the client-window.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using iframe. Thanks